# Collectionview displays dotted page indicators on the right side on Apple TV

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I am using `collectionView` for listing objects in **Apple TV** but when scrolling the contents vertically it shows a dotted line in the right side(Screenshot Attached) and it gets hidden automatically on scroll end.

Is there any way to disable this. Looks like code for hiding the vertical and *horizontal scroll indicator* doesn't works here

```
[collectionView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your scroll view's `indexDisplayMode` to `UIScrollViewIndexDisplayModeAlwaysHidden`.